# Can't subtract registers in an addressing mode?

Tags: assembly, x86, inline-assembly, addressing-mode

I finished reading PC Assembly Language and I was working on an implementation of RC4 encryption in Assembly. What I can't comprehend is why

```
mov eax, [edx+ecx]
```

works but

```
mov eax, [edx-ecx]
```

doesn't. The inline assembler gives me this error message,

> non-constant expression in 'second operand'

What does that mean? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In general, see [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34058101) for the available addressing modes.  Only addition, but you can use a negative constant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following gives a good summary of x86 addressing modes. Note that there is no "register minus register" form: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#Addressing_modes).

As a workaround, you could negate the contents of `ecx` then use `[edx+ecx]` (you may have to negate it back if you need the original value afterwards).

Comment: Or: mov eax,edx; sub eax, ecx, mov eax,[eax]. This saves you the extra negation

Answer (score 7):

There is an opcode for:

```
mov eax, [edx+ecx]
```

and there is an opcode which can be assembled from:

```
mov eax, [edx-CONSTANT]
```

because the assembler uses the regular opcode but negates the constant during assembly:

```
mov eax, [edx+(-CONSTANT)]
```

However there is not an opcode for:

```
mov eax, [edx-ecx]
```

So basically you're attempting to execute an instruction that doesn't exist.

Comment: Terminology: different addressing modes are encoded by the ModRM byte which follows the opcode byte (except for some opcodes that only have implicit and/or immediate operands and don't have a ModRM).  The only case where there are special opcodes for an addressing mode is x86-64 `movabs al/ax/eax/rax, [abs64]` with a 64-bit absolute address as part of the machine code, loading or storing the accumulator.  (So four opcodes, byte vs. non-byte and load vs. store, with the size for the non-byte opcode determined by prefixes.)

Answer (score 1):

You're not allowed to subtract in the offset like that.  The intent is that you can point at the base of a memory buffer and then *add* an offset into it.  Subtraction would result in pulling you out of the specified memory buffer...