# Invalid 64-bit effective address error in asm nasm 64-bit

Tags: assembly, nasm

I make custom function for reverse a string by this prototype

```
char *my_strrev(const char *s);
```

I implemented a custom light weight **malloc** function for my needs.

Here is my full function

```
section .text
global my_strrev

my_strrev:  
; Input:
 ;   RDI - Pointer to string; 
; Output: 
;   RAX - Pointer to reversed string
  mov rcx, 0   ; Counter
.length: 
  mov al, [rdi] 
  cmp al, 0
  je .malloc
  inc rcx
  inc rdi
  jmp .length

.malloc:
  push rdi 
  push rcx

  mov rsi, rcx     
  mov rax, 0x09  ; mmap
  mov rdi, 0x00
  mov r10, 0x22  ; Flag
  mov rdx, 0x03   
  mov r8, -0x01  
  mov r9, 0x0  

  syscall

  pop rcx
  pop rdi
  xor rsi, rsi
.reverse:
  mov al, [rdi - rsi]
  mov [rax + rsi], al 
  inc rsi             
  dec rcx 
  cmp rcx, 0       
  je .done          
  jmp .reverse

.done: 
  ret
```

When I try to compile it with

```
nasm -f elf64 my_strrev.s
```

I fall to error in this statement

```
mov al, [rdi - rsi]: error: invalid 64-bit effective address
```

If I put

```
mov al, [rdi - 0]
```

Or any another digit in hard it works.

If I try

```
mov al, [rdi]
mov [rax], al

...
inc rax
dec rdi
```

II can see in gdb like rdi moves but rax is empty

UPDATE
I try that

```
section .text
global my_strrev

my_strrev:
    ; Entrée:
    ;   RDI - Pointeur vers la chaîne de caractère
    ; Sortie:
    ;   RAX - Pointeur vers la chaîne de caractères inversée

    mov rcx, 0     ; RCX = 0 (longueur de la chaîne)
    push rdi
    
.length:
    mov al, [rdi] 
    cmp al, 0     
    je .malloc 
    inc rdi       
    inc rcx       
    jmp .length

.malloc:
    push rcx

    mov rsi, rcx     
    mov rax, 0x09
    mov rdi, 0x00
    mov r10, 0x22  ; Flag
    mov rdx, 0x03   
    mov r8, -0x01  
    mov r9, 0x0  

    syscall

    pop rcx
    dec rcx
    pop rdi
    mov rsi, 0

.reverse:   
    mov al, [rdi + rcx]
    mov [rax + rsi], al
    inc rsi             ; Incrémente l'indice de début
    dec rcx
    cmp rcx, 0        ; Vérifie si nous avons inversé toute la chaîne
    je .done           ; Si oui, sort de la boucle
    jmp .reverse

.done:
    ret
```

in first iteration of .reverse loop I get that

```
$rax   : 0x00007ffff7fc3072  →  0x0000000000000072 ("r"?)
```

but second gives it

```
$rax   : 0x00007ffff7fc3075  →  0x0000000000000000
```

**SOLVED**

here is the functional code

```
section .text
global my_strrev

my_strrev:
    ; Entrée:
    ;   RDI - Pointeur vers la chaîne de caractère
    ; Sortie:
    ;   RAX - Pointeur vers la chaîne de caractères inversée

    mov rcx, 0     ; RCX = 0 (longueur de la chaîne)
    
.length:
    mov al, [rdi] 
    cmp al, 0     
    je .malloc 
    inc rdi       
    inc rcx       
    jmp .length

.malloc:
    push rdi
    push rcx

    mov rsi, rcx     
    mov rax, 0x09
    mov rdi, 0x00
    mov r10, 0x22  ; Flag
    mov rdx, 0x03   
    mov r8, -0x01  
    mov r9, 0x0  

    syscall

    pop rcx ; counter
    pop rdi ; input pointer on the end
    mov rsi, 0
    dec rdi

.reverse:   
    mov r10, rdi
    sub r10, rsi
    mov bl, [r10]
    mov [rax + rsi], bl
    inc rsi             ; Incrémente l'indice de début
    cmp rcx, rsi        ; Vérifie si nous avons inversé toute la chaîne
    je .done           ; Si oui, sort de la boucle
    jmp .reverse

.done:
    mov byte [rax + rsi], 0
    ret
```

the most important thing was that I used **al** in **.reverse** loop and as it is a low byte of **rax** register I rewrite the same register!

Hope it will be useful for someone later

Comment: See the linked duplicate ([Can't subtract registers in an addressing mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5513513)) and [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34058101) .  Unlike ARM, x86 addressing modes can't subtract registers, only add regs and signed (possibly negative) immediates.

Comment: Use a temporary register to calculate the subtraction, or use pointer increments.  AL is the low byte of RAX, so overwriting part of your pointer with string data is a problem.

Comment: PS: the fun way to do this is using `bswap` to reverse 8 bytes at a time, or `pshufb` to reverse 16.

Comment: updated question

Comment: AL is still the low byte of RAX.  Pick a different byte register, one you're not already using for indexing.  Still a duplicate of [How do AX, AH, AL map onto EAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15191178).  As you can see from your debugger, loading into AL is changing the low byte of RAX, which you're still using to hold a pointer (the mmap return value which should be page-aligned, low 12 bits = 3 hex digits = 0).